# Why I can't read firestore data?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a data for each user in Firebase Firestore, When I try to read the data it gives me this error and the screen doesn't open, it freezes in the splash screen

```
W/DynamiteModule(10111): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
I/DynamiteModule(10111): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0
W/ProviderInstaller(10111): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
D/TrafficStats(10111): tagSocket(134) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
```

this is the error I've got.

I've tried to add the data in an array and then print elements from array and it gives me null values

```
Future<void> readFirestoreData() async {
  try {
    QuerySnapshot userQuery = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('email', isEqualTo: user?.email)
        .get();

    if (userQuery.docs.isEmpty) {
      data.addAll(userQuery.docs);
      print(data);
      setState(() {
        age = data[0]['age'];
        weight = data[0]['weight'];
        height = data[0]['height'];
        gender = data[0]['gender'];
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error while reading firestore data: $e');
  }
}
```

also I tried another method to read the data and in that method it freezes in the splash screen

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MainScreenState createState() => MainScreenState();
}

class MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  var age;
  var weight;
  var height;
  var gender;

  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> data = [];

  bool checkUser() {
    if (user == null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  Future getUserData() async {
    try {
      final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .where("email", isEqualTo: user?.email)
          .get();

      if (querySnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        var userData = querySnapshot.docs[0].data();
        age = userData['age'];
        gender = userData['gender'];
        height = userData['height'];
        weight = userData['weight'];
      } else {
        print('User not found for email: ${user?.email}');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error fetching user data: $e');
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() async {
    super.initState();
    await getUserData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: checkUser()
            ? Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text('You have logged in successfully'),
                  Text('Gender: $gender'),
                  Text('Age: $age'),
                  Text('Height: $height'),
                  Text('Weight: $weight'),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () async {
                      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                      Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                          context, '/loginscreen', (route) => false);
                    },
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.logout,
                      color: AppColors.LightThemeApp,
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              )
            : Text('Not Signed'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to don't use the function **getUserData** and only print the **user?.email** from firebase authentication it worked and but when I uses the function it doesn't work and I'm sure that there is a data exists with that email. So I think there is some issues from the firestore.

Comment: did u update ur firebase settings ?

Comment: yes I've checked everything and still have the error

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering, specifically the message "Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found", suggests that there might be an issue with the Google Play services setup in your app. This can sometimes lead to unexpected behavior or errors when interacting with Firebase services.

Here are some steps you can take to troubleshoot and potentially resolve the issue:

- Check Google Play services setup: Make sure that your app is properly
  configured to use Google Play services.
- Ensure that you are using the latest version of the Firebase SDK in your app.
- Verify that your Firebase project settings are correct, including the configuration file (google-services.json for Android) and the enabled Firebase services.
- Try running app in your mobile phone instead of emulator. I had solved one of my issues with the same way.
- Make sure that your Firestore security rules allow read access to the users collection for authenticated users.

Comment: I have checked all what you mentioned and I have the same error also